# Can I remove NULL and bounds checks if I use SAL?

Tags: c, visual-studio, annotations, static-analysis, sal

How much can I rely on SAL? Do I need to do

```
NSTATUS my_func(_In_ int *p)
{
    if (NULL == p) {
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }
    *p = 1;
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

or can I just do

```
NTSTATUS my_func(_In_ int *p)
{
    *p = 1;
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to be tagged `C` instead of `C++`?

Comment: @EOF - Sorry for such long delay! Yes, I'm writing windows kernel drivers using C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAL only provides static checks at compile time. This assumes that all code involved has the appropriate annotations and has also been checked. This is okay internal to your application or module but be careful at boundaries with other libraries.

Comment: Wow I just now saw that this question got answered! Clicked the checkmark for you, sorry for super long delay. Would upvote you, too, but it looks like I need 15 reputation for that.